# One of several recessed lights on a dimmer making a faint ringing noise

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting, lightning

I have compatible, dimmable LED light bulbs for my recessed fixtures and they are the correct watts. However, when on, one of the recessed lights makes a distinct but faint ringing noise. This is the case in two separate rooms. Any idea what is causing this?

Answers:
Yes, this is most definitely a ringing noise. Yes, they are LED bulbs. In each of the two rooms which have several fixtures, only one makes the noise.

Comment: Using edits to answer comment questions is the prefer way.   Is it a ringing noise or a humming(more common) noise?  Are these LEDs or another type of light bulb?

Comment: Editing your question is usually the correct thing to do, but you should be able to comment/respond to comments on **your own question**, IIRC even if you have not hit the threshold for commening on others' questions. I'm sensitive to annoying noises and had one set of LED lights (dimmable) and LED-compatible dimmer that just resulted in unacceptable audible noise. Rather than try to hunt down a dimmer that didn't make them sing, I just went back to a normal switch on that set of lights, and they shut up. Dimming wasn't that important to me for those light locations.

Comment: There are many posts here of  wierd behaviour of led lights, especially dimmable ones. I  gave up on mine and removed the dimmers on all led lights. The strip lights still seem to work fine with dimmers

Comment: Post updated with answers. Thanks for all the help. It sounds like I may just have to put up with it or get rid of the dimmer! (Yay, I can finally comment!)

Answer (score 1):

The current regulators in LED lamps run at high frequencies, and the transformers inside can make a high-pitched whine or hiss due to magnetostriction. In many lamps, the transformers are "potted" in plastic to reduce that noise,  but the potting compound might not have been applied evenly. If the lamps are easily changed (e.g., a bi-pin replacement for fluorescent lamp, or an Edison-base replacement for an incandescent), try another lamp, and put the noisier ones in a location that will not matter, e.g., garage or outside fixture.